# Why is ButtonStateXY() always returning empty for Launchpad X using Launchpad.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I run ButtonStateXY() it is always returning empty.
Here is my code:
https://pastebin.com/QdhrEQrR
`

```
        while going:
            button = lp.ButtonStateXY()
            print(button)
            curbeat = (time.perf_counter() - startTime)*16/SpB
            curlight = [x for x in lightmap if x[1] <= curbeat]
            curnotes = [x for x in notemap if x[2] <= curbeat+7]
 
            for lights in curlight:
                lp.LedCtrlXY(lights[0][0], lights[0][1], lights[0][2], lights[0][3], lights[0][4])
                lightmap.remove(lights)
```

`
It should return the list of buttons pressed but it returns empty. I am using https://github.com/FMMT666/launchpad.py. I have tried using Raw Button and running test code and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Fix: Put 1 in the open(1) Statement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).